Eth stuck on base bridge
Can you pleas help me i have my eth stuck for almost 8 months ago here the tx: 0x3ff7eedefc7d8023de04bdb11595b47404718ac96cd3c1524784705361475f7e

Transaction once they are present in the blockchain either succeed or fail immediately. Did you try asking the bridge operator about your ether? That transaction is with Optimism Bridge. The transaction by itself doesn't provide enough information about the wallets involved.
